# How do I root Xperia ZQ_6025?

Tags: rooting, root-access, sony-xperia

How do I root this phone and any risk of losing Ltd for my region?

Comment: @RossC The question you linked is an index of questions about rooting, so this question should be added to the index, not duplicated.

Comment: @DanHulme sorry totally mixed that up. My apologies. Removed comment, and well ignore the flag.

Comment: Ok. This was my first question. I'll try again.

Comment: @user54320 that was MY mistake, not yours! My apologies to you. The question is fine! Since I'm writing this I wanted to add just be careful and patient. Get a stock ROM downloaded first, in case you want to restore it. Get all the root tools. Make some folders for ROMs / Recovery / Backups and so on. Do it slowly and methodically and keep reading information. It is possible to brick the device and the more you know, and the more prepared you are the better! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Check on [xda-developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xperia-zl) for your device. Search for root in Xperia zL/zQ forum. (Isn't Xperia zQ also known as xperia ZL in other parts?)

Rooting will void your warranty and in very rare cases can also brick your phone. Follow all instruction given very carefully.

Rooting probably will not affect Lte for your region.